# IOS Prevent text from stacking on screen rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, screen-orientation

I have a custom table view cell with two labels in it. If I rotate the screen the two labels stack on top of each other and behave badly. If I back out and display the view again while still in landscape mode they appear correctly.

I have figured out how to prevent this between a label and a textfield or a webview by pinning them with horizontal spacing, but that doesn't seem to be possible with two labels. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: It certainly is possible with two labels. I don't know what you tried, but putting a spacing constraint between the two labels should work fine -- make sure you don't have other constraints (to the edges) that might be preventing the spacing from being correct.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to intercept the viewcontroller rotation delegate callbacks and handle them how you want by manually positioning labels on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think all views should be re-positioned again in `viewWillLaypitSubviews` or `viewDidLaypitSubviews` methods. Otherwise, the resizing decision is put to iOS. If you don't want a resize, you can try playing with the `autoResizingmask` and `autoResizeSubviews` properties of the table view cell.